# How to use putExtras with multiple buttons

Tags: java, android

I want to use `putExtras` with if statement in getExtras. If in first activity I click an image, it should perform an action, but when I click other image in first activity, it should perform another action.

Here is my code, code works but know not how to differentiate between actions in next activity:

```
public class wuu extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9;
    frix_wuxu aa = new frix_wuxu();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wuu);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.second);
        final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("abc", "a");
        extras.putString("name", "b");

        t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(wuzu.this, frix_wuxu.class);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        t2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(wuzu.this, frix_wuxu.class);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add another value in `putExtra` as flag. Usually you can achieve it by using an enum like this:

```
public Enum Action {
  ONE, TWO
}
```

then add it to your Extra:

```
final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("abc", "a");
extras.putString("name", "b");

// add the action 
extras.putSerializable("action", Action.ONE);
```

---

The better ways is by packing the whole of your data and `Action` as a pojo like this:

```
// You can also use Parcelable instead of Serializable.
public class MyData implement Serializable {
  private String abc;
  private String name;
  private Action action;

  // constructor
  // setter
  // getter
}
```

then you can use it for your Extras:

```
MyData myData = new MyData();
myData.setAbc("a");
myData.setName("b");
myDaya.setAction(Action.ONE);
final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putSerializable("myData", myData);
```

to read it in your next Activiy, you can use this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

MyData myData = (MyData) bundle.getSerializable("myData");

// then do something by the action:
switch (myData.getAction) {
   case ONE:
     // do something
   break;
   case TWO:
     // do something
   break;
}
```